# Why is $\frac{1}{2^\left(l+k\right)} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^\left(l-k\right) * \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^k$?

Tags: transformation

I am quite confused about this weird transformation

Comment: Use $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$

Comment: The right hand side can be written as $\frac{1}{2^{l-k}}\frac{1}{2^{2k}}$. Hint: $l-k+2k=l+k$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac{1}{2^{\ell + k}} = \dfrac{1}{2^{\ell - k + 2k}} = \dfrac{1}{2^{\ell - k}\cdot 2^{2k}} = \dfrac{1}{2^{\ell - k}}\cdot \dfrac{1}{2^{2k}} = \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{\ell - k} \cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{2^2}\right)^k = \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{\ell - k}\cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^k$$

Comment: Thx. I would have never thought of this. Do you just need a lot of excercise to see things like this?

Comment: @OnionBread Surely practicing will help you. Those exercises are made for this, I guess. Learning those tricks, manipulations of exponents, properties of powers and so on. In my opinion, $\frac{1}{2^{\ell + k}}$ is the best wasy to write it, but just for the sake of practice, one has to be able to run such tricks. They will come in handy in the future (especially with integrals).